# XML - SelectNodes - How to get nodes with attribute with some value (MFC)

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, mfc, msxml

I am working in MFC

I would like to get all nodes from XML , with attribute with some value but value should not be null, and should not select node if no attribute present

```
<node att="sss"> - should be selected
<node att="sd342ss"> - should be selected
<node att=""> - empty value should not be selected
<node > - not having attribute should not be selected
```

**how to create XPATH for this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a structure like:

```
<root>
    <node att="sss" />
    <node att="sd342ss" /> 
    <node att="" />
    <node />
</root>
```

Your XPath to select only nodes which have an attribute and where the attribute's value is not empty would look something like:

```
"//node[@att and string-length(@att) > 0]"
```